# Little-oh and Little-omega Time Complexity

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, limit, calculus

From what I know, the little-oh should have a limit of n approaching infinity of (function/little-oh,omega function) that = 0 and for little omega, the limit should equal infinity. However, is it possible for there to be multiple little-oh's and little-omegas that would make the limit true?

That is, is it possible that there are many little-ohs and little-omegas that would fit a single equation?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Little-o is a kind of upper bound, and little-omega is a kind of lower bound.  In general any upper bound for a known upper bound is itself an upper bound.  And likewise any lower bound of a known lower bound is itself a lower bound.  So there are always infinitely many upper bounds and usually infinitely many lower bounds.

The reason for the "usually" among lower bounds is that `0` has no lower bounds among non-negative functions, and generally in time complexity you never will find anything that is little-omega of a constant.  But if `f(n)` goes to infinity then you've got `log(f(n))`, `log(log(f(n))`, `log(log(log(f(n)))`, ... for an infinite series of lower bounds.

As for upper bounds, it is "always" because you can multiply any positive function by `n`, `n^2`, `n^3`, ... to get an infinite number of strictly bigger upper bounds.